# DeviceAgent-Runner quit unexpectedly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I made a simple Xamarin.iOS app with a UI Test App project just to learn how to make automated UI test. I am using VSMac 2019 and following the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/

I installed the Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent nugget in my iOS project and added in my `FinishedLaunching` method:

```
#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
Xamarin.Calabash.Start();
#endif
```

My `AppInitializer` class in my UI Test App project:

```
public class AppInitializer
{
    public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
    {
        // TODO: If the iOS or Android app being tested is included in the solution 
        // then open the Unit Tests window, right click Test Apps, select Add App Project
        // and select the app projects that should be tested.
        //
        // The iOS project should have the Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent NuGet package
        // installed. To start the Test Cloud Agent the following code should be
        // added to the FinishedLaunching method of the AppDelegate:
        //
        //    #if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
        //    Xamarin.Calabash.Start();
        //    #endif
        if (platform == Platform.Android)
        {
            return ConfigureApp
                .Android
                // TODO: Update this path to point to your Android app and uncomment the
                // code if the app is not included in the solution.
                //.ApkFile ("../../../Droid/bin/Debug/xamarinforms.apk")
                .StartApp();
        }

        return ConfigureApp.iOS
                           .EnableLocalScreenshots()
                           .DeviceIdentifier("3C0B5D32-8722-4A1C-BA6B-C13B3E3D3952")
                           .InstalledApp("com.drake.MyAppTest")
                           .StartApp();
    }
}
```

It opens my simulator, installs the DeviceAgent app but then immediately crashes with this report:

> ### ------------------------------------- Translated Report (Full Report Below)
>
> Incident Identifier: 42E3018F-F6AD-4A2D-BC85-F56CF5043C19
> CrashReporter Key:   CEC4770B-BEBD-CF8B-2D6A-E9045B038C60 Hardware
> Model:      MacBookPro16,1 Process:             DeviceAgent-Runner
> [81642] Path:
> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C0B5D32-8722-4A1C-BA6B-C13B3E3D3952/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/96AEC496-0C00-46F8-82DD-53187D30D145/DeviceAgent-Runner.app/DeviceAgent-Runner Identifier:          com.apple.test.DeviceAgent-Runner Version:
> 2.2.3 (1605115037) Code Type:           X86-64 (Native) Role:                Non UI Parent Process:      launchd_sim [81025] Coalition:
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.3C0B5D32-8722-4A1C-BA6B-C13B3E3D3952
> [28614] Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1005]
>
> Date/Time:           2023-01-10 16:15:23.1423 -0500 Launch Time:
> 2023-01-10 16:15:22.7223 -0500 OS Version:          macOS 13.0.1
> (22A400) Release Type:        User Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
> 0x7ff80042889b __exceptionPreprocess + 226 1   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x7ff80004dba3 objc_exception_throw + 48 2   Foundation                         0x7ff800b87271 -[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary) classForCoder] + 0 3   XCTest
> 0x10ac8c700 _XCTestMain + 761 4   DeviceAgent-Runner
> 0x10a69702d -[_XCTRunnerAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] + 0
> 5   DeviceAgent-Runner                       0x10a696f2b
> _XCTRunnerRunTests + 0 6   CoreFoundation                     0x7ff800387dd9 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12 7
> CoreFoundation                        0x7ff800387592 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
>
> - 406 8   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800381e38 __CFRunLoopRun + 948 9   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003816a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560 10  GraphicsServices
>   0x7ff809cb128a GSEventRunModal + 139 11  UIKitCore                             0x111f20ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994 12  UIKitCore                               0x111f259ef UIApplicationMain + 123 13  DeviceAgent-Runner                      0x10a6971f5 main + 183 14  dyld_sim                                 0x10a84f2bf start_sim + 10 15  dyld
>   0x1167cb310 start + 2432
>
> Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
> libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x7ff83611d30e __pthread_kill + 10
> 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x7ff836175f7b pthread_kill +
> 263 2   libsystem_c.dylib                     0x7ff800132fe0 abort + 130
> 3   libc++abi.dylib                       0x7ff800258742 abort_message +
> 241 4   libc++abi.dylib                       0x7ff80024995d
> demangling_terminate_handler() + 266 5   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x7ff800032082 _objc_terminate() + 96 6   libc++abi.dylib                       0x7ff800257b65 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8 7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80025a3a4 __cxa_rethrow + 99 8
> libobjc.A.dylib                       0x7ff80004dd0d
> objc_exception_rethrow + 37 9   CoreFoundation
> 0x7ff800381769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 754 10  GraphicsServices
> 0x7ff809cb128a GSEventRunModal + 139 11  UIKitCore                             0x111f20ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994 12  UIKitCore                               0x111f259ef UIApplicationMain + 123 13  DeviceAgent-Runner                      0x10a6971f5 main + 183 14  dyld_sim                                 0x10a84f2bf start_sim + 10 15  dyld
> 0x1167cb310 start + 2432
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff836171c58
> start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 2::  Dispatch queue: AXCodeLoader 0   CoreFoundation
> 0x7ff80036007e -[__NSCFString retain] + 5 1   AccessibilityUtilities                0x7ff809d43c4f -[AXCodeLoader
> _accessibilityCodeItemMatchingName:type:path:] + 703 2   AccessibilityUtilities               0x7ff809d43f9e -[AXCodeLoader
> _associateAccessibilityCodeItemWithLoadedCodeItem:] + 334 3   AccessibilityUtilities              0x7ff809d41b41 __36-[AXCodeLoader
> _addTrackedCodeItem:]_block_invoke + 273 4   libdispatch.dylib                    0x7ff80013b7fb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 5   libdispatch.dylib                  0x7ff80013ca3a
> _dispatch_client_callout + 8 6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x7ff800144346 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 949 7   libdispatch.dylib
> 0x7ff800144fe3 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 400 8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x7ff800151b46 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 870 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x7ff836172ce3 _pthread_wqthread +
> 326 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x7ff836171c67
> start_wqthread + 15
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff836171c58
> start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 4:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread 0
> libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x7ff8361166a2 mach_msg2_trap + 10
> 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x7ff83612467d
> mach_msg2_internal + 82 2   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x7ff83611d71a mach_msg_overwrite + 723 3   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x7ff836116989 mach_msg + 19 4   CoreFoundation                     0x7ff80038788e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145 5   CoreFoundation
> 0x7ff800381fdf __CFRunLoopRun + 1371 6   CoreFoundation                     0x7ff8003816a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560 7   Foundation                            0x7ff800c568b4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 213 8   Foundation                         0x7ff800c56b2d
> -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 72 9   UIKitCore                             0x111ff6286 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 535 10  Foundation                            0x7ff800c8011b **NSThread__start** + 1009 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x7ff836176259 _pthread_start + 125
> 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x7ff836171c7b thread_start +
> 15
>
> Thread 5: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff836171c58
> start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 6: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff836171c58
> start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
> 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00000001168692c0  rcx: 0x00007ff7b5868748
> rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000000103  rsi:
> 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ff7b5868770  rsp: 0x00007ff7b5868748
> r8: 0x00007ff7b5868610   r9: 0x00007ff7b5868870  r10:
> 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246   r12: 0x0000000000000103
> r13: 0x0000003000000008  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15:
> 0x0000000000000016   rip: 0x00007ff83611d30e  rfl: 0x0000000000000246
> cr2: 0x00007ff800132f5e    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:
> 0x02000148  Trap Number:     133
>
> Binary Images:
> 0x7ff836115000 -     0x7ff83614eff7 libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <0c2fd2c9-777c-3355-b70f-7b1b6e9d1b0b>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x7ff836170000 -     0x7ff83617bff7 libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <13b5e252-77d1-31e1-888d-1c5f4426ea87>
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
> 0x7ff8000b5000 -     0x7ff800139ff7 libsystem_c.dylib (*) <8a60f5c1-ea1f-352b-b778-967be44e3677>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x7ff800248000 -     0x7ff80025dffb libc++abi.dylib (*) 
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
> 0x7ff80002c000 -     0x7ff80005ffe9 libobjc.A.dylib (*) <2a7a213a-fdb2-311c-81d7-efdfd9ddf25a>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x7ff800303000 -     0x7ff80068bffc com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <2be0f79f-8b25-3614-9e7e-dbac565f72dd>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
> 0x7ff809cae000 -     0x7ff809cb5ff2 com.apple.GraphicsServices (1.0) <16365e42-1d5c-363d-84d1-3bb290a43253>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
> 0x1110df000 -        0x112baafff com.apple.UIKitCore (1.0) 
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
> 0x10a695000 -        0x10a69afff com.apple.test.DeviceAgent-Runner (2.2.3)
> <21a4d4bc-72d4-3a0e-9786-17e33f61a799>
> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C0B5D32-8722-4A1C-BA6B-C13B3E3D3952/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/96AEC496-0C00-46F8-82DD-53187D30D145/DeviceAgent-Runner.app/DeviceAgent-Runner
> 0x10a84d000 -        0x10a8acfff dyld_sim (*) <6fb74554-3370-3677-93d4-7f7a01ea6a80>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
> 0x1167c5000 -        0x11685cfff dyld (*) <28fd2071-57f3-3873-87bf-e4f674a82de6> /usr/lib/dyld
> 0x7ff809cb6000 -     0x7ff809e5dff1 com.apple.AccessibilityUtilities (1.0.0)
> <50cb8d29-b910-3d47-9032-8587768224fa>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities
> 0x7ff80013a000 -     0x7ff800185ff3 libdispatch.dylib (*) <59be51c1-e9f3-3a60-8108-cd70ae082897>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
> 0x7ff8006fe000 -     0x7ff80102eff4 com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <86cd050d-44fc-3045-a1f3-8ad5047b329e>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
> 0x10ac01000 -        0x10acf5fff com.apple.dt.XCTest (1.0) 
> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C0B5D32-8722-4A1C-BA6B-C13B3E3D3952/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/96AEC496-0C00-46F8-82DD-53187D30D145/DeviceAgent-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
>
> EOF
>
> ### ----------- Full Report
>
> {"app_name":"DeviceAgent-Runner","timestamp":"2023-01-10 16:15:23.00
> -0500","app_version":"2.2.3","slice_uuid":"21a4d4bc-72d4-3a0e-9786-17e33f61a799","build_version":"1605115037","platform":7,"bundleID":"com.apple.test.DeviceAgent-Runner","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS
> 13.0.1 (22A400)","roots_installed":0,"name":"DeviceAgent-Runner","incident_id":"42E3018F-F6AD-4A2D-BC85-F56CF5043C19"}
> {   "uptime" : 310000,   "procRole" : "Non UI",   "version" : 2,
> "userID" : 501,   "deployVersion" : 210,   "modelCode" :
> "MacBookPro16,1",   "coalitionID" : 28614,   "osVersion" : {
> "train" : "macOS 13.0.1",
> "build" : "22A400",
> "releaseType" : "User"   },   "captureTime" : "2023-01-10 16:15:23.1423 -0500",   "incident" :
> "42E3018F-F6AD-4A2D-BC85-F56CF5043C19",   "pid" : 81642,   "cpuType" :
> "X86-64",   "roots_installed" : 0,   "bug_type" : "309",
> "procLaunch" : "2023-01-10 16:15:22.7223 -0500",   "procStartAbsTime"
> : 317186299226018,   "procExitAbsTime" : 317186718671602,   "procName"
> : "DeviceAgent-Runner",   "procPath" :
> "/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C0B5D32-8722-4A1C-BA6B-C13B3E3D3952/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/96AEC496-0C00-46F8-82DD-53187D30D145/DeviceAgent-Runner.app/DeviceAgent-Runner",
> "bundleInfo" :
> {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"2.2.3","CFBundleVersion":"1605115037","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.test.DeviceAgent-Runner"},
> "storeInfo" :
> {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"37FA7600-3C07-5A77-BDA0-2BC56C48EE9E","thirdParty":true},
> "parentProc" : "launchd_sim",   "parentPid" : 81025,   "coalitionName"
> :
> "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.3C0B5D32-8722-4A1C-BA6B-C13B3E3D3952",
> "crashReporterKey" : "CEC4770B-BEBD-CF8B-2D6A-E9045B038C60",
> "responsiblePid" : 1005,   "responsibleProc" : "SimulatorTrampoline",
> "wakeTime" : 2282,   "bridgeVersion" :
> {"build":"20P420","train":"7.0"},   "sleepWakeUUID" :
> "0F2539EC-DDFE-4381-82F1-C578B4701148",   "sip" : "enabled",
> "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000,
> 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
> "asiBacktraces" : ["0   CoreFoundation
> 0x00007ff8004288ab __exceptionPreprocess + 242\n1   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x00007ff80004dba3 objc_exception_throw + 48\n2   Foundation
> 0x00007ff800b87271 -[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary)
> classForCoder] + 0\n3   XCTest
> 0x000000010ac8c700 _XCTestMain + 761\n4   DeviceAgent-Runner
> 0x000000010a69702d -[_XCTRunnerAppDelegate
> applicationWillResignActive:] + 0\n5   DeviceAgent-Runner
> 0x000000010a696f2b _XCTRunnerRunTests + 0\n6   CoreFoundation
> 0x00007ff800387dd9 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12\n7
> CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff800387592
> __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 406\n8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff800381e38 __CFRunLoopRun + 948\n9   CoreFoundation
> 0x00007ff8003816a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560\n10  GraphicsServices
> 0x00007ff809cb128a GSEventRunModal + 139\n11  UIKitCore
> 0x0000000111f20ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994\n12  UIKitCore
> 0x0000000111f259ef UIApplicationMain + 123\n13  DeviceAgent-Runner
> 0x000000010a6971f5 main + 183\n14  dyld
> 0x000000010a84f2bf start_sim + 10\n15  ???
> 0x00000001167cb310 0x0 + 4672238352"],   "extMods" :
> {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":18},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
> "lastExceptionBacktrace" :
> [{"imageOffset":1202331,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":226,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":138147,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":48,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":4756081,"symbol":"-[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary)
> classForCoder]","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":571136,"symbol":"_XCTestMain","symbolLocation":761,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":8237,"symbol":"-[_XCTRunnerAppDelegate
> applicationWillResignActive:]","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":7979,"symbol":"_XCTRunnerRunTests","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":544217,"symbol":"**CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK**","symbolLocation":12,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":542098,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoBlocks","symbolLocation":406,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":519736,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":948,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":517799,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":560,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":12938,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":139,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":14949075,"symbol":"-[UIApplication
> _run]","symbolLocation":994,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":14969327,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":123,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":8693,"symbol":"main","symbolLocation":183,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":8895,"symbol":"start_sim","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":25360,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2432,"imageIndex":10}],
> "faultingThread" : 0,   "threads" :
> [{"triggered":true,"id":3080438,"threadState":{"r13":{"value":206158430216},"rax":{"value":0},"rflags":{"value":582},"cpu":{"value":0},"r14":{"value":6},"rsi":{"value":6},"r8":{"value":140701879141904},"cr2":{"value":140703129874270},"rdx":{"value":0},"r10":{"value":0},"r9":{"value":140701879142512},"r15":{"value":22},"rbx":{"value":4672885440,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_main_thread"},"trap":{"value":133},"err":{"value":33554760},"r11":{"value":582},"rip":{"value":140704035754766,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"rbp":{"value":140701879142256},"rsp":{"value":140701879142216},"r12":{"value":259},"rcx":{"value":140701879142216},"flavor":"x86_THREAD_STATE","rdi":{"value":259}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":33550,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":24443,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":263,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":516064,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":130,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":67394,"symbol":"abort_message","symbolLocation":241,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":6493,"symbol":"demangling_terminate_handler()","symbolLocation":266,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":24706,"symbol":"_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":96,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":64357,"symbol":"std::__terminate(void
> (*)())","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":74660,"symbol":"__cxa_rethrow","symbolLocation":99,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":138509,"symbol":"objc_exception_rethrow","symbolLocation":37,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":517993,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":754,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":12938,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":139,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":14949075,"symbol":"-[UIApplication
> _run]","symbolLocation":994,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":14969327,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":123,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":8693,"symbol":"main","symbolLocation":183,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":8895,"symbol":"start_sim","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":25360,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2432,"imageIndex":10}]},{"id":3080469,"frames":[{"imageOffset":7256,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":3080470,"queue":"AXCodeLoader","frames":[{"imageOffset":381054,"symbol":"-[__NSCFString
> retain]","symbolLocation":5,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":580687,"symbol":"-[AXCodeLoader
> _accessibilityCodeItemMatchingName:type:path:]","symbolLocation":703,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":581534,"symbol":"-[AXCodeLoader
> _associateAccessibilityCodeItemWithLoadedCodeItem:]","symbolLocation":334,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":572225,"symbol":"__36-[AXCodeLoader
> _addTrackedCodeItem:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":273,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":6139,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":12,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":10810,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":41798,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":949,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":45027,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":400,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":97094,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":870,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":11491,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":326,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":7271,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":3080471,"frames":[{"imageOffset":7256,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":3080472,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":5794,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":63101,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":82,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":34586,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":723,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":6537,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":19,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":542862,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":145,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":520159,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1371,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":517799,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":560,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":5605556,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop)
> runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":213,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":5606189,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop)
> runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":72,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":15823494,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher
> threadMain]","symbolLocation":535,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":5775643,"symbol":"**NSThread__start**","symbolLocation":1009,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":25177,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":7291,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":3080473,"frames":[{"imageOffset":7256,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]},{"id":3080474,"frames":[{"imageOffset":7256,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}]}],
> "usedImages" : [   {
> "source" : "P",
> "arch" : "x86_64",
> "base" : 140704035721216,
> "size" : 237560,
> "uuid" : "0c2fd2c9-777c-3355-b70f-7b1b6e9d1b0b",
> "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
> "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"   },   {
> "source" : "P",
> "arch" : "x86_64",
> "base" : 140704036093952,
> "size" : 49144,
> "uuid" : "13b5e252-77d1-31e1-888d-1c5f4426ea87",
> "path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
> "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"   },   {
> "source" : "P",
> "arch" : "x86_64",
> "base" : 140703129358336,
> "size" : 544760,
> "uuid" : "8a60f5c1-ea1f-352b-b778-967be44e3677",
> "path" : "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib",
> "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"   },   {
> "source" : "P",
> "arch" : "x86_64",
> "base" : 140703131009024,
> "size" : 90108,
> "uuid" : "ae8cbd53-0926-3251-b648-6f32d9330a50",
> "path" : "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib",
> "name" : "libc++abi.dylib"   },   {
> "source" : "P",
> "arch" : "x86_64",
> "base" : 140703128797184,
> "size" : 212970,
> "uuid" : "2a7a213a-fdb2-311c-81d7-efdfd9ddf25a",
> "path" : "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib",
> "name" : "libobjc.A.dylib"   },   {
> "source" : "P",
> "arch" : "x86_64",
> "base" : 140703131774976,
> "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
> "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.CoreFoundation",
> "size" : 3706877,
> "uuid" : "2be0f79f-8b25-3614-9e7e-dbac565f72dd",
> "path" : "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation",

**EDIT**

I noticed in the logs of the test result window:

> 023-01-10 21:04:33.843 DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302] Running
> tests... 2023-01-10 21:04:33.845 DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302]
> Unable to load configuration data from specified path ; error: The
> file name is invalid. 2023-01-10 21:04:33.845
> DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302] Unable to load configuration data
> from specified path ; error: The file name is invalid. 2023-01-10
> 21:04:33.848 DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302] Found most recent test
> bundle at NSBundle
> </Users/drake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B7B33614-1706-4361-8A0F-EE12175686CC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8CD92CE7-5550-4E8A-99B8-BCC0DD6147F9/DeviceAgent-Runner.app/PlugIns/DeviceAgent.xctest>
> (not yet loaded) 2023-01-10 21:04:33.848
> DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302] Found most recent test configuration
> in bundle:
> /Users/drake/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B7B33614-1706-4361-8A0F-EE12175686CC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8CD92CE7-5550-4E8A-99B8-BCC0DD6147F9/DeviceAgent-Runner.app/PlugIns/DeviceAgent.xctest/CBX.xctestconfiguration
> 2023-01-10 21:04:33.850 DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302] clearing out
> IDE related attributes 2023-01-10 21:04:33.850
> DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302] Running with configuration
> <XCTestConfiguration: 0x600000a245b0> 2023-01-10 21:04:33.854
> DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302] *** Assertion failure in void
> _XCTestMain(XCTestConfiguration *__strong _Nonnull)(), /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest_Sim/XCTest-14460.20/Sources/XCTestFramework/Harness/XCTestMain.m:213
> 2023-01-10 21:04:33.856 DeviceAgent-Runner[90901:3282302] ***
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No test bundle found at
> file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/21A83AF9-FACE-FACE-FACE-00605F990879/UITest-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITest.xctest'
> 2023-01-10 21:04:34.158 xcodebuild[90891:3282023] [MT]
> IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
> 2023-01-10 21:04:34.158 xcodebuild[90891:3282023] [MT]
> IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 1.940 elapsed -- Testing started
> completed. 2023-01-10 21:04:34.158 xcodebuild[90891:3282023] [MT]
> IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 1.940 sec, +1.940 sec -- end
> 2023-01-10 21:04:34.217 xcodebuild[90891:3282023] [MT] IDEResultKit:
> Warning: While writing a result bundle to
> /var/folders/jn/t9rq3scj2v13v8cmvl7kw2h80000gn/T/xdb/logs/2023.01.10.210431/DerivedData/Logs/Test/Test-Transient
> Testing-2023.01.10_21-04-32--0500.xcresult, not all contents have been
> imported, as the Staging directory still contains the following
> files/directories: ["1_Test"]

Do I need to include a path to a configuration somewhere?

**EDIT 2**

I notice there is no reference to `Xamarin.Calabash` if I remove the `#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD`. Is there another package I need to add to my project?

Comment: Did you find anything out about this since you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of `UITest.xctest`. The error message in your edit indicates there is no test bundle.

```
No test bundle found at file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/21A83AF9-FACE-FACE-FACE-00605F990879/UITest-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITest.xctest
```

Comment: I feel dumb for asking this, but how I can I find this folder in Finder?